# Partition by ignoring some columns

Tags: sql, oracle, partitioning

I have this in the query:

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY (NUMB) ORDER BY MY_COL2) AS row_number`

this will pretty much equally assign values depending on the `NUMB` variable.
I actually need to skip assignments for some columns where `MY_COL3 LIKE 'exclude'`

Is there an easy way to do it incorporating the logic above?

Since if there is not, I have to create two separate queries and use the assignment above in one query, and do no assign anything in another (with exclude) and then union both queries. The problem is that this is very time consuming and large query and I want to avoid it... Looking for a quick fix if there is one...

More details:

this what query does now (simplified) based on NUMB=4:

`ROW NUMBER | USER | TEXT | STATUS | 
1 | Bill | blah1 | GOOD
1 | Bill | blah2 | Exclude
2 | Jack | blah3 | GOOD
2 | Jack | blah4 | Exclude
3 | Will | blah5 | GOOD
3 | Will | blah6 | Exclude
4 | Andy | blah7 | GOOD
4 | Andy | blah8 | GOOD`

This is what I want:

`ROW NUMBER | USER | TEXT | STATUS | 
1 | Bill | blah1 | GOOD
  | Bill | blah2 | Exclude
1 | Jack | blah3 | GOOD
  | Jack | blah4 | Exclude
2 | Will | blah5 | GOOD
  | Will | blah6 | Exclude
3 | Andy | blah7 | GOOD
4 | Andy | blah8 | GOOD`

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Do you not want to partition when `MY_COL3 like exclude`, or not want to generate a row_number, or something else?

Comment: Could you select from a subquery `where MY_COL3 NOT LIKE 'exclude'`? If not, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rows can be excluded from the row number by using two `case` statements.  The first one creates two separate `partition by`, one for excluded rows and one
 for rows you care about.  The outer `case` then displays null for the excluded rows.

```
select
    case
        when status = 'Exclude' then
            null
        else
            row_number() over
            (
                partition by case when status = 'Exclude' then 0 else 1 end
                order by numb
            )
    end new_rownumber,
    data.*
from
(
    select 1 numb, 'Bill' name, 'blah1' text, 'GOOD'    status from dual union all
    select 1 numb, 'Bill' name, 'blah2' text, 'Exclude' status from dual union all
    select 2 numb, 'Jack' name, 'blah3' text, 'GOOD'    status from dual union all
    select 2 numb, 'Jack' name, 'blah4' text, 'Exclude' status from dual union all
    select 3 numb, 'Will' name, 'blah5' text, 'GOOD'    status from dual union all
    select 3 numb, 'Will' name, 'blah6' text, 'Exclude' status from dual union all
    select 4 numb, 'Andy' name, 'blah7' text, 'GOOD'    status from dual union all
    select 4 numb, 'Andy' name, 'blah8' text, 'GOOD'    status from dual 
) data
order by numb, status desc;
```

The results don't exactly match.  The example uses 1 twice for the new row number - is that a mistake?

```
NEW_ROWNUMBER   NUMB   NAME   TEST    STATUS
-------------   ----   ----   ----    ------
1               1      Bill    blah1  GOOD
                1      Bill    blah2  Exclude
2               2      Jack    blah3  GOOD
                2      Jack    blah4  Exclude
3               3      Will    blah5  GOOD
                3      Will    blah6  Exclude
5               4      Andy    blah7  GOOD
4               4      Andy    blah8  GOOD
```